# Binomial random variable/z-score question?

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients

I was given the problem: 
 In a restaurant called ”Allegory”, on average 1 in 10 people order a bottle of white wine. Out of
a sample of 50 people 11 chose a bottle of white wine. Has this wine become more popular? Test
at the 1% level of significance.

In the solution, when computing the z-score they calculated that SD=  √4.5. How did they get this? Also, how did they know that this was a binomial random variable?

ie. What markers should I look for in determining what type of random variable/test I should use?

Comment: $\sqrt{(50)(1/10)(9/10)}$.

Comment: "How did they get this?" If $X \sim B(n,p)$, then $SD=\sqrt{n \times p \times (1-p)}$. Here $n=50, p=0.1$ giving $SD=\sqrt{50 \times 0.1 \times 0.9}=\sqrt{4.5}$.